# twig template display articles from specific date

Tags: php, twig

I am making a site using twig php template.

I want to display the articles published in November.
So far I have this:

```
{% if date(article.published) == date('november') %}

    {% for article in articles %}

    <li> <a href="/articles/{{ article.slug }}">{{ article.title }}</a> </li>

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: Can't you add a `WHERE` condition in your database query in order to filter articles instead of using Twig for filtering articles?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `IF` clause inside of the loop, not outside of it:

```
{% for article in articles %}

    {% if date(article.published) == date('november') %}

        <li> <a href="/articles/{{ article.slug }}">{{ article.title }}</a> </li>

    {% endif %} 

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
{% 
   if article.published|date('U') > '2014-11-01'|date('U')
   and article.published|date('U') < '2014-12-01'|date('U')
%}
```

The `date('U')` filter will convert dates to the timestamp format (number of secs since 1970-01-01), so we can do some dates comparisons from here and filter all dates between 2014-11-01 and 2014-11-31 23:59:59.

And as @Giedrius pointed out, you should put the if inside the loop.

This becomes:

```
{% for article in articles %}

    {% 
       if article.published|date('U') > '2014-11-01'|date('U')
       and article.published|date('U') < '2014-12-01'|date('U')
    %}

        <li> <a href="/articles/{{ article.slug }}">{{ article.title }}</a> </li>

    {% endif %} 

{% endfor %}
```